# Click multiple Webpages inside another Webpage - Python 3.5 using selenium in Windows 7 (64-bit)

Tags: python, selenium

[script I am trying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRk50.png)

In the website for Foreclosure, I am first entering the city names looping it through i in city. Inside that loop I need to click on "View Details" button for all the foreclosure properties.
I ended up with moving to 1st city, clicking on the 1st "View Details" and then moving on to the next city and so on.
My 2nd loop of clicking "View Details" is somehow forgetting which URL to start again and ends up with going back to the 1st loop.

Can someone help me with how to write the loop where I can click and enter inside every "View Details" button and then browsing back. It will move to the 2nd city only when all the results of 1st city are being checked.

P.S. I am using Selenium in Python 3.5 and Windows 7 (64-bit).
Link used : https://www.foreclosure.com/

Comment: A minimal code example would be very helpful.

Comment: Click on "script i am trying"... I have given there.